# Checkbox: Content-binding based on multiple fields

Tags: silverlight, data-binding

I currently have a `combobox` with `checkboxes` as items.

```
        <ComboBox Height="25" Width="70" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="cbDivision" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <CheckBox Tag="{Binding DivID}" Content="{Binding DivDescr}" Checked="CheckBox_Checked" Unchecked="CheckBox_Unchecked" ></CheckBox>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>
```

I want to change the format of my content in those textboxes to:

```
DivDescr(DivID)
```

I tried using the following methods but so far no luck:

```
Content="{Binding DivDescr(Binding DivID)}"
Content="{Binding DivDescr}({Binding DivID})"
```

Could anyone point me to the right answer?

Thank you for your time

Comment: Is this Silverlight or WPF as this changes things?

Comment: Silverlight. Sorry will remove the tag. Must have misclicked somewhere

Comment: Then I think the easiest thing will be to create concatenated property that would return _DivDescr(DivID)_ and bind to that

Comment: @dkozl Jups that seemed to bring me the right format. Thank you for that.  so `Multibinding`is a WPF-only solution?

Comment: Unfortunately yes. Silverlight is stripped from things like `MultiBinding` and `IMultiValueConverter`

Answer (score 1):

The target of your binding needs to be a property, not a method. Based on your xaml, it looks like the object being bound to has the DivID already, so I would create a property that wraps the call you are trying to make.

```
public string DivDescrResult
{
    get { return DivDescr(DivID);}
}
...
Content="{Binding DivDescrResult}"
```